# Azure DevOps ServiceConnection Roles Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How can I modify Azure DevOps ServiceConnection Roles using the REST API?

This is the corresponding UI

[image]

I want to add a team within the 'User' role.

I have been looking at

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/security%20namespaces?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20lists?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

is this the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below api to update security for service connection.

```
Put https://dev.azure.com/<Org>/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.serviceendpointrole/roleassignments/resources/<resourcesId>?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
```

The API is not documented. But you can find it when you F12 your browser.

You can get the resourceId from the request url in F12 page.

[image]

And also from the URL of the **Service Connection** UI page url and also
[image]

Below is example in powershell scripts:

```
$url="https://dev.azure.com/<org>/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.serviceendpointrole/roleassignments/resources/......c5_d69e94f6-9c07-4341-bd6f-8b28e05d4b08?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

$connectionToken ="Personal Access token"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$body ='[{"roleName":"User","userId":"....a313-31d7848bcdcc"}]'

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method put  -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```

Above script with assign the user to **User** role permission for the service connection.

You can get the user id from the request body in F12 page. But you may still need to use below rest api to [get the user id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users/{userDescriptor}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

You can get the userDescriptor from the URL in UI page of the **Permission** page for each user.
[image]

Comment: I would like to add one AAD group as role "User" what will be the Body? tried to use AAD Group Object Id as Userid but not working. Can you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

watch out for the url... this contains the ProjectId_ServiceEndpointId

```
$url="https://dev.azure.com/$OrganizationName/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.serviceendpointrole/roleassignments/resources/$($ProjectId)_$($ServiceEndpointId)?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
```

ProjectId from

```
https://dev.azure.com/$OrganizatioName/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1
```

UserId from [property: originId]

```
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$OrganizatioName/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

ServiceEndpointId from

```
https://dev.azure.com/$OrganizatioName/$ProjectId/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```